# How can we achive to get top Video_Id from this query..?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT VIDEO_ID,MAX(VIDEO) AS MAX 
FROM (SELECT VIDEO_ID,AVG(VIDEO_RATING)AS VIDEO 
      FROM VIDEO_RATING_TABLE 
      GROUP BY VIDEO_ID)T 
GROUP BY VIDEO_ID;
```

This what I was able to get `MAX(AVG)`. The result of this query is this:

```
|VIDEO_ID | MAX    |  PLACE_ID

|        1 | 3.6667 |  1

|        2 | 4.0000 |  1 

|        3 | 4.5714 |  2
```

but I want the `VIDEO_ID` from this table whose `max` is greatest ORDER BY PLACE_ID.
SO VIDEO_ID SHOULD BE 2,3....I MIGHT HAVE MULTIPLE VIDEO FOR SINGLE PLACE,I NEED TOP VIDEO FROM EACH PLACE....AND A WHERE CLAUSE TO ENTER THE PLACE_ID BY USER....

```
| VIDEO_ID | VIDEO_RATING | PLCAE_ID| USER_ID       | VIDEO_RATING_ID |

|        1 |            5 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |               1 |

|        1 |            5 | 000001 | Z@gmail.com    |               2 |

|        1 |            1 | 000002 | YTER@gmail.com |               3 |

|        2 |            1 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |               4 |

|        2 |            5 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |               5 |

|        2 |            5 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |               6 |

|        2 |            5 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |               7 |

|        3 |            5 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |               8 |

|        3 |            4 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |               9 |

|        3 |            3 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |              10 |

|        3 |            5 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |              11 |

|        3 |            5 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |              12 |

|        3 |            5 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |              13 |

|        3 |            5 | 000001 | YTER@gmail.com |              14 |
```

previous query gives error saying ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You can add the `ORDER BY` clause to you query:

```
SELECT VIDEO_ID,MAX(VIDEO) AS MAX 
FROM (
    SELECT VIDEO_ID,AVG(VIDEO_RATING)AS VIDEO 
    FROM VIDEO_RATING_TABLE 
    GROUP BY VIDEO_ID)T 
GROUP BY VIDEO_ID 
ORDER BY MAX DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It will sort the table in descending order of `MAX` and selects the first row.

The result will be:

```
VIDEO_ID    MAX
3           4.5714
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52b6/1)

**OR** you can add a `WHERE` clause to your query and remove the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT VIDEO_ID,VIDEO AS MAX 
FROM (
    SELECT VIDEO_ID,AVG(VIDEO_RATING)AS VIDEO 
    FROM VIDEO_RATING_TABLE 
    GROUP BY VIDEO_ID)T 
WHERE VIDEO=MAX(VIDEO)
```

It will select `VIDEO_ID` and `AVG(VIDEO_RATING)` which has the highest `AVG(VIDEO_RATING)`.

**EDIT:**

As per the new question, try this:

```
SET @PlaceID =-1 ;
SELECT VIDEO_ID,MAX(MAX) as MAX,PLACE_ID 
FROM (SELECT VIDEO_ID,MAX(VIDEO) AS MAX,PLACE_ID 
      FROM (SELECT VIDEO_ID,AVG(VIDEO_RATING)AS VIDEO,PLACE_ID 
            FROM VIDEO_RATING_TABLE 
            GROUP BY VIDEO_ID,PLACE_ID)T 
      GROUP BY VIDEO_ID,PLACE_ID;)
WHERE (@PlaceID =-1 OR PLACE_ID=@PlaceID)
GROUP BY PLACE_ID
```

Pass user entered `PLACE_ID` as `@PlaceID`, it will select the maximum rating in that place.

See example in [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39f17/3)

**Added another trick:** If you want to see maximum of all places, then pass -1 as `@PlaceID`.

See example in [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39f17/1)

Note: If you are willing to show us some sample data in the table `VIDEO_RATING_TABLE`, I hope we can optimize the query which will improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

preppend `ORDER BY`MAX`DESC LIMIT 1;` to your query

```
SELECT VIDEO_ID,MAX(VIDEO) AS `MAX` FROM (SELECT VIDEO_ID,AVG(VIDEO_RATING)AS VIDEO FROM VIDEO_RATING_TABLE  GROUP BY VIDEO_ID)T GROUP BY VIDEO_ID ORDER BY `MAX` DESC LIMIT 1;
```